# How to render wagtail orderable to homepage template?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to render them for my home templates. How can I solve the issue to get the output on templates? I created snippets and orderable and now can't get the output in my homepage. I tried with related_name="question_answer" but it is not working here.

````
    @register_snippet
    class Question(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
        panels = [
            FieldPanel('text'),
            FieldPanel('slug')
        ]
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.text
    
    
    class Answer(Orderable, models.Model):
        page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="question_answer")
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = '+')
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    
        panels = [
            MultiFieldPanel([
                SnippetChooserPanel('question'),
            ], heading="Questions"),
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('answer'),
                FieldPanel('url'),
            ], heading="Answers & Urls")
        ]
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.page.title + " -> " + self.question.text
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Setting `related_name="question_answer"` on the ParentalKey means that you can access the Answer objects related to the page as `page.question_answer.all()`. So, in your template, you can do something like:

```
<h1>Answers</h1>
<ul>
    {% for item in page.question_answer.all %}
        <li>{{ item.answer }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know what went wrong here. I tried it before and now but it is not working here.